# Using MSBuild, how can I run Exec for every N items in a list?

Tags: msbuild, mstest

Originally, I wanted to load a list of tests from a file and invoke each test in its own MSTest instance. The script fragment below accomplishes this:

```
<ReadLinesFromFile
  File="$(SolutionDir)\TestList.txt" 
  >
  <Output
    TaskParameter="Lines"
    ItemName="TestsFromFile"
    />
</ReadLinesFromFile>

<ItemGroup>
  <Commands Include='&quot;$(VS100COMNTOOLS)\..\IDE\mstest.exe&quot; /runconfig:$(ParsedTestSettings) /testcontainer:$(ParsedTestContainer) /unique /test:%(TestsFromFile.Identity) /resultsfile:$(SolutionDir)\AnalysisResults\%(TestsFromFile.Identity).trx'/>
</ItemGroup>

<Exec
  Condition="'@(Tests)' != ''" 
  IgnoreExitCode="true"
  Command='%(Commands.Identity)'
  >
  <Output TaskParameter="exitcode" ItemName="exitcodes"/>
</Exec>
```

However, let's say that instead of executing one instance of mstest.exe per test, I want one instance of mstest.exe per 10 tests, or per N tests. Is there a way to get MSBuild to run the exec task for N tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using stijn's suggestion, below is the inline task. Note that the GroupSize property lets me control how many items are included for each Exec task.

```
<UsingTask
  TaskName="GenerateTestOptionsCollection"
  TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
  AssemblyFile="$(MicrosoftBuildTasksPath)"
  >
  <ParameterGroup>
    <SolutionDir
      ParameterType="System.String"
      Required="true"
      />
    <GroupSize
      ParameterType="System.Int32"
      Required="true"
      />
    <TestNames 
      ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" 
      Required="true" 
      />
    <TestOptions
      ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" 
      Output="true"
      />
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Code 
      Type="Fragment"
      Language="cs"
      >
      <![CDATA[
          var optionGroups = new List<string>();
          var optionItems = new List<TaskItem>();

          for (var j = 0; j < TestNames.Length; j++)
          {
              optionGroups.Add("/test:" + TestNames[j].ItemSpec);

              if (((j + 1) % GroupSize == 0) || j == (TestNames.Length - 1))
              {
                  var options = string.Join(" ", optionGroups) + " " + "/resultsfile:" + SolutionDir + "\\AnalysisResults\\" + optionItems.Count + ".trx";
                  optionItems.Add(new TaskItem(options));
                  optionGroups.Clear();
              }
          }

          TestOptions = optionItems.ToArray();
      ]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

Using the inline task:

```
<ReadLinesFromFile
  File="$(SolutionDir)\TestList.txt" 
  >
  <Output
    TaskParameter="Lines"
    ItemName="TestsFromFile"
    />
</ReadLinesFromFile>

<GenerateTestOptionsCollection
  SolutionDir="$(SolutionDir)"
  GroupSize="$(GroupSize)"
  TestNames="@(TestsFromFile)"
  >
  <Output ItemName="Commands" TaskParameter="TestOptions"/>
</GenerateTestOptionsCollection>

<Exec
  Condition="'@(Tests)' != ''" 
  IgnoreExitCode="true"
  Command='&quot;$(VS100COMNTOOLS)\..\IDE\mstest.exe&quot; /runconfig:$(ParsedTestSettings) /testcontainer:$(ParsedTestContainer) /unique %(Commands.Identity)'
  >
  <Output TaskParameter="exitcode" ItemName="exitcodes"/>
</Exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom build task and pass the list in. [Creating the build task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx) is simple, and in the Execute() override you simply loop over the list and spawn MSTest at whatever frequency you want.

Comment: or with the latest msbuild, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx might do it as well